# Connect a client to a server?

Tags: c, network-programming, client, server

I have a simple question for you. I'm trying to make a simple client-server program. I want to connect the client to the server but I get the following error: Can't connect to the server. I'm new with this and this is why I can;t figure out what the problem is. Please give me some hints. Here is my client/server code:

Client:

```
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdint.h>

int main(){
    int socketc;
    int connectnr;
    int c;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char buffer[256];

    socketc = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(socketc < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Can't create client socket.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(4321);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    connectnr = connect(c, (struct sockaddr *) & server, sizeof(struct    sockaddr_in));
    if(connectnr < 0){
        printf("connectnr %d: \n", connectnr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Can't connect to the server.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    close(c);
}
```

Server:

```
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int c;

int main(){
    int connsocket;
    int bindcod;
    int l;
    struct sockaddr_in client, server;

connsocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(connsocket < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Can't create the server socket.\n");
    return 1;
}

memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(4321);
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

bindcod = bind(connsocket, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
if(bindcod < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Con't establish the bind. Port is already used.\n");
    return 1;
}

listen(connsocket, 5);

while(1){
    memset(&client, 0, sizeof(client));
    l = sizeof(client);
    printf("Waiting for the client to connect,\n");
    c = accept(connsocket, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &l);
    printf("New client connected with address %s and port %d.\n", inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr), ntohs(client.sin_port));
}
}
```

Comment: In case of failure let the client print the value of `errno`, this might help you to identify the root cause of the failure.

Comment: on server add `#include<arpa/inet.h>`

Comment: In client.c file the arguments to connect(c,...) function is wrong. You should use socketc instead of c

Comment: After editing i get "Segmentation fauld"...The Server does not respond that a client is now connected. I can't find what that means

Comment: `int l;` should be `socklen_t l;`

Answer (score 1):

You are giving wrong socket to connect function.

Replace

> connect(c, (struct sockaddr *) & server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

with

> connect(**socketc** , (struct sockaddr *) & server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));